# psql command will not work in cli MAC. ERR: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed

Tags: macos, command-line, postgresql

I have installed home-brew v14 psql & psql app v14.

It will not allow me to use port 5432 (I spent a week getting this to work and it hasnt), so I have made a server on 4321 which will start.
when I type psql in my cli, I get the below error:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

I cannot find the tmp folder to change the port to listen too. Any help will be appreciated.

I was able to manually change the port back to 5432 in the postgresapp  which worked.

now I get this error message when I tap 'psql' in the command line:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "edac" does not exist
```

Comment: tmp folder is `cd /tmp` in Terminal However that will not fix the issue. What is the exact command line you use to run psql? Also how is your server set up?

Comment: its is just my Mac terminal I am using. the server is setup in my Postgres app.

Comment: Pleas provide details of what the setup is.

Comment: could you clarify on what you mean by details of setup? Postgres 14 was installed via home brew. I then installed the Postgres app in which I created my server, is this what you mean? apologies if im missing something, quite new to postgres

Comment: What socket does the Postgress app use, what user is psql using and what user is defined for the server? What configuration have you set in the app?

Comment: How did you install the app?

Comment: ALso probably easier to use the command line tools from the app not a different set. See https://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html

Comment: I installed Postgres with home-brew and installed the app directly from the Postgres website. I've not set anything up in the app, there was a default server in there which I am trying to use. yes, I am using the cli tools from the app. which use 'psql' as the command. How do I find out what socket it is using?

Comment: I've found my pgsql_socket folder which is empty. should there be something within it?

Comment: The error about a missing role means you're almost there. Try connecting with ```psql -u <your username> postgres```. If that fails, try  -u root. ```brew info postgres``` shows you the initdb command it runs to set everything up. Try rerunning that if it still does not work. It also shows you the postgres data directory (/opt/Homebrew/var/postgres vor me). Check ../log from there to find the logs.

Comment: still couldn't get it to work. for some reason when I type psql Postgres I can get into it, but it denies me permission to create a db